# why does my function return 0 in a sub in VBA

Tags: vba

```
Function jaineqtn(Rcoeff As Single)
Dim F_old As Single
F_old = 1.325 / (WorksheetFunction.Ln(Rcoeff / 3.7)) ^ 2
End Function

Sub Macro1()
Dim val As Single
val = jaineqtn(5)
MsgBox val

End Sub
```

Comment: A function always returns a value, unlike a sub which returns nothing to the caller. If you do not set the value that the function returns within the function itself, then the return value is the default 0.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock: In this particular case, the return value is `Empty`, not `0`, since the Function has an implicit return value type of `Variant`. Of course, `Empty` gets coerced to `0` when it is assigned to a `Single` later.

Answer (score 3):

> why does my function return 0 in a sub in VBA

Because your Function returns `Empty`:

```
Function jaineqtn(Rcoeff As Single)
Dim F_old As Single
F_old = 1.325 / (WorksheetFunction.Ln(Rcoeff / 3.7)) ^ 2
End Function
```

You declare a local variable `F_old`, but you never set a return value.  Thus, your function, having an implicit return value type of [`Variant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/variant-data-type), will return Variant's default value, which is `Empty`.

Then, in your Sub `Macro1`, you assign that default return value to a variable of type `Single`. [Assigning `Empty` to a `Single` yields `0`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/glossary/vbe-glossary#empty)

Maybe you meant to write the following?

```
Function jaineqtn(Rcoeff As Single) As Single
    jaineqtn = 1.325 / (WorksheetFunction.Ln(Rcoeff / 3.7)) ^ 2
End Function
```

Comment: yeahh that is where i was wrong ...it is working now

Comment: Maybe you should add that `Option Explicit` would cause a compile error, in that the return type is not defined?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock: Unfortunately, `Option Explicit` won't help here - it just disallows undeclared variables. We'd need `Option Strict On`, but that's only available in VB.NET.